# SVN (with connector) doesn't work after/before installing Scala plugin eclipse

Tags: scala, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo, svnkit

I installed **Eclipse Indigo**, then I installed SVN. After restarting I was asked to choose my SVN Connector (I choose **SVNKit 1.7.10**). At this point, everything is working.

Then I installed the **Groovy plugin**, and everything is still working.

Then I installed the **Scala plugin**, and suddenly after restarting Eclipse my SVN has stopped working. It was installed etc., but it isn't working.

I figured, I needed to install the Scala plugin first. Then I installed SVN but after restarting I didn't get the message about choosing an SVN Connector, so I installed it manually. Still doesn't work.

Is this a bug? How do I fix it?

Comment: Which SVN plugin are you using? I would recommend Subclipse. Maybe there won't be a conflict with that one: http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Comment: I have always used the SubClipse plugin and never had an issue with it.

Just make sure you get the right version of the plugin for the version of SVN you're using - (SubClipse supports several)

Comment: thanks guy, it worked ;) it also works with scala nightly plugin (i meant subversive not subclipse) so if someone will have this issue in the future, read comment meaby it will help!